# how to save second column value into text file from table when first column checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

[image]

html page contains table checkbox in 1st column other columns as values. I want to save second columns data into a text file when checkbox is checked and save button is clicked.i have provided textbox to enter file name.
User can check all or any checkbox and give text file name in the textbox to save data into file.
**problem is when click save button its take only 1st value of 2nd column. even if i check all checkboxes.**

Its killing me, please someone help...

**fiddle for this:- [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a66tfmay)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <script>
         function checkAll(ele) {
             var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
             if (ele.checked) {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
             } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            console.log(i)
            if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
            }
        }
             }
         }
        </script>

<script>
function Info() {
        next_page='ccc.php'
        checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
                checkbox.onclick = function() {
                var currentRow = this.parentNode.parentNode;
                var secondColumn = currentRow.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];

                form = document.createElement('form');
                form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
                form.setAttribute('action', next_page);

                opt = 'save';
                myvar = document.createElement('input');
                myvar.setAttribute('name', opt);
                myvar.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                myvar.setAttribute('value', opt);
                form.appendChild(myvar);

                text = secondColumn.textContent;
                myvar1 = document.createElement('input');
                myvar1.setAttribute('name', 'text');
                myvar1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
                myvar1.setAttribute('value', text);
                form.appendChild(myvar1);

                document.body.appendChild(form);
                form.submit();
                };
        }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="testlist" border=1>
<tr style="font-family:verdana;font-size:16px"><th>Select All<input type="checkbox"  style="zoom:1.5" onchange="checkAll(this)" name="chk[]"></th><th>TestCase Name</th> <th>TestCase Group</th> <th>Description</th></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5"><td>A</td> <td>ALL_A</td> <td>This Test A</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5"><td>B</td> <td>ALL_B</td> <td>This Test B</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5"><td>C</td> <td>ALL_C</td> <td>This Test C.</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5"><td>D</td> <td>ALL_D</td> <td>This Test D.</td></tr>
</table>
<label for="tc_file"><b>Enter File Name:  </b></label><input type="text" name="tc_file" placeholder="Like ABC">
<input type="button" name="save" onClick="Info()" value="Save to File" style="height:35px;width:110px"/>    <input type="button" onclick="location.href='add_newtc.php';" value="Add New Test" style="height:35px;width:110px"/>
</div>
<?php
        $fileName = "tc_list.txt";
        $tc_name = $_POST["text"];
        ob_start();
        echo "$tc_name";
        $obStr = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        file_put_contents($fileName, $obStr." \n", FILE_APPEND);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: fiddle for this:- https://jsfiddle.net/a66tfmay/

Comment: Please edit your question and put your fiddle in there.

Comment: Can you also perhaps have a picture of what you are trying to do. I am having a hard time understanding your question.

Comment: i want to save 2nd column value into text file if save button is clicked and checkbox is checked in the first column. to provide text file name i have given text field below the table.please check the fiddle link in above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution to your problem:

```
<table id="testlist" border=1>
<tr style="font-family:verdana;font-size:16px">
    <th>Select All
    <input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5" onchange="checkAll(this)" name="chk[]">
    </th>
    <th>TestCase Name</th>
    <th>TestCase Group</th>
    <th>Description</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5">
    <td>A</td>
    <td>ALL_A</td>
    <td>This Test A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5">
    <td>B</td>
    <td>ALL_B</td>
    <td>This Test B</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5">
    <td>C</td>
    <td>ALL_C</td>
    <td>This Test C.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
    <input type="checkbox" style="zoom:1.5">
    <td>D</td>
    <td>ALL_D</td>
    <td>This Test D.</td>
</tr>
</table>
<label for="tc_file"><b>Enter File Name:  </b></label>
<input type="text" name="tc_file" placeholder="Like ABC">
<input type="button" name="save" onClick="Info()" value="Save to File" style="height:35px;width:110px" />
<input type="button" onclick="location.href='add_newtc.php';" value="Add New Test" style="height:35px;width:110px" />

<script language=javascript>
    function checkAll(ele) {
        var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        if (ele.checked) {
            for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
                }
            }
        } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
                    console.log(i)
                    if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                        checkboxes[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    function Info() {
        var next_page = 'ccc.php'
        var itemCount = 0;
        var table = document.getElementById("testlist");
        var rows = table.rows;
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
        form.setAttribute('action', next_page);

        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
            row = rows[i];
            cells = row.cells;
            firstCol = cells[0];
            secondCol = cells[1];

            if (firstCol.firstElementChild.checked) {
            myvar1 = document.createElement('input');
            myvar1.setAttribute('name', 'tc' + (itemCount++));
            myvar1.setAttribute('type', 'text');
            myvar1.setAttribute('value', secondCol.innerHTML);
            form.appendChild(myvar1);
            }
        }
        if (itemCount > 0) {
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            form.submit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because you did not give unique name for each checkbox.

Comment: tried using getting entire 2nd column value , but its not checking for checkboxes..